# Changing the order of $\sup$ and $\inf$

Tags: convexity, minimax

I have a problem in the following form

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{cll}
\sup_{\theta \in \mathrm{dom}(f)} &  \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \underbrace{f(\theta)}_{\text{concave in $\theta$}} + \underbrace{\theta \cdot z^{\top} c}_{\text{linear in $\theta$ and $z$}} \\
& \mathrm{subject\;to} & \underbrace{g(\theta, z)}_{\text{convex in $\theta$ and $z$}} \leq 0.
\end{array}
\end{align}

What conditions do we need so to be able to change the order of $\sup$ and $\inf$? Notice that when the outer problem fixes $\theta$ the inner problem behaves well, as the objective is linear in $z$ and the constraints are convex. On the other hand, if we fix some $z$ value, then the objective is convex in $\theta$ (as it becomes concave maximization) and again the constraints are convex in $\theta$.

Proposition 5.5.4 of Convex Optimization Theory by Bertsekas gives conditions to change the order of $\sup$ and $\inf$, but there the constraints are separable in the sense that there is no constraint like $g(\theta, z) \leq 0$; rather, $\theta \in \Theta$ and $z \in Z$, separately.

Comment: "A first-order augmented Lagrangian method for constrained minimax optimization" by Lu and Mei (2023) takes a similar problem, but more on the solution strategy. I think there are not many cases where we can swap the sup and inf.

Comment: Is it better to do $\text{sup}_z~\text{inf}_\theta$ ?